# unable to get data.length of object

Tags: jquery

```
$.each(value , function (k, v){//data
 $.each(v , function (key, data){//conversations/contacts
     console.log(data.length);//undefined
  });
});

console.log(data);//logs out below:

Object { 0={...},  1={...},  totalConversations="3"}
```

There are two objects at the moment, so it should return 2 but it says undefined.

I learned that only array has length and to get object length, agai I tried this:

```
console.log(Object.keys(data).length);
```

but this gives me 3. I don;t understand how it gets 3 since there are only two objects. Well, what's the correct way to get data's length please?

Comment: "I don;t understand how it gets 3", because your example output is `Object { 0={...},  1={...},  totalConversations="3"}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log(Object.keys(data).length);//returns 3
```

Object.keys() basically return array containing the keys of your object in your case it is ["0","1","totalConversations"]

You can do this simply:

```
var data={"0":{"name":"xt"},"1":{"name":"jjdjdjd"},"noOFcount":"4"}
var count=0;
$.each(data , function (k, v){//data
    if(typeof(v)==="object"){ count++;
    }
});
console.log(count); // returns 2
```

Comment: thanks for explaining..but I need it to count only the objects..what's the way?